# No errors in Eclipse but will not run on Blackberry Simulator. Error 104 illegalmonitorstateexception

Tags: blackberry-simulator

When running the App in the simulator i get the error msg App Error 104 illegalmonitorstateexception on startup.
There are no errors from within Eclipse and the Simulator works on other code so nothing wrong there i think.

Code:

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;

class hello extends UiApplication {
hello() {
    MainScreen SCREEN = new MainScreen();
    SCREEN.setTitle("mygismo.com");

    // CREATE STRING

    String[] mymsgs = { "Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives" };

    // AND INITIATE LOOP

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        // UPDATE SCREEN

        SCREEN.add(new LabelField(mymsgs[i]));
        pushScreen(SCREEN);

        // WAIT 5 seconds

        try {
            wait(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    hello APP = new hello();
    APP.enterEventDispatcher();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same screen over and over again.
That's the problem.